# Prompted for password by ssh when trying to connect to Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've followed a couple of tutorials for creating an Amazon EC2 instance using the command line tools

http://www.zabada.com/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-application-to-production-on-amazon-ec2.php
http://www.smartfrog.org/wiki/display/sf/Starting+an+EC2+Image+by+Hand

and all is well, i

- ec2-add-keypair (directing the output of ec2-add-keypair directly to a file in ~/.ssh)
- chmod 600 the keypair
- ec2-run-instance
- ec2-describe-instances

then, when the new instance is running try to ssh on

ssh -i ~/.ssh/ec2-keypair ec2-user@foo.bar.amazon.com

At this point i'm ALWAYS prompted for a password. Obviously there's no password so it always refuses me access.

My question is, what am i doing wrong here? Why am i being prompted for a password and how can i put this right so i can ssh onto the machine i've just started?

I'm guessing this is something to do with my local setup, but as far as i know this machine hasn't had anything custom done with .ssh (there's certainly no config file or anything like that lying around that might be screwing with things).

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: From which AMI did you create your instance? The username you have to choose isn't always the same.

Comment: Sounds like you've created your private key with a passphrase. How did you create your key pair? Did you enter a passphrase when you created your private key?

Answer (score 3):

`ec2-user@` ? Why not `root@` ?

Comment: i used ec2-user cause when i've created instances on the amazon console and tried to log in as root its told me to log in as ec2-user

Comment: A lot of EC2 information implies the user name is usually or always `ec2-user`.  Not true.  It can be `root` for CentOS, `ubuntu` for Ubuntu etc.  And for whatever reason, the user name is not documented with the AMI!  Very irritating.